# Double Recursion in Assembly works until secondary recursion becomes larger than the base case

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I am trying to code a Assembly program that will ask for an integer and perform a recursive function: `if n>5 f(n) = n*f(n-1)-f(n-3)+n-23 else n<=5 f(n)=15-2n` I managed to get the first instance of recursion of the `n*f(n-1)`but when it goes for the second recursion of `f(n-3)` it performs the second portion improperly.

During the calculations, if I input 8 as the integer, the result should be 20 which I get but, when I input anything greater than 8 because then the second recursion hits an integer larger than 5 (the base case) I get an incorrect answer. Basically any input larger than 8 doesn't work
For example the correct answers are:

```
f(9) = 162
f(10) = 1602
f(11) = 17590
```

The answers I get

```
f(9)= 27
f(10)=22 
f(11)=23
```

Here is my code:

````
    ```#data declarations: declare variable names used in program, storage allocated in RAM
                                .data   
    prompt1:    .asciiz "\nEnter an Integer:\n" #Ending Index
    message1:   .asciiz "\nThe Solution is:\n"
    answer: .word   0


    #program code is contained below under .text
                            .text 
                            .globl    main    #define a global function main

    # the program begins execution at main()

    main:   
        la  $a0, prompt1    #load address of prompt1
        li  $v0, 4      #prepare print string
        syscall
        li  $v0, 5      #prepare receive int
        syscall
        move    $a0, $v0

        addi    $sp, $sp, -4
        sw  $ra, 0($sp) 
        jal Function
        sw  $v0, answer #move returned answer to a new memory
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4

        la  $a0, message1   #load address of message1
        li  $v0, 4      #prepare print string
        syscall
        lw  $a0, answer
        li  $v0, 1
        syscall

        jr  $ra
    ############################################################################
    # Procedure/Function Function1
    # Description: recursive math function
    # parameters: $a0 = value of n, 
    # return value: $v0 = answer
    # registers to be used: $s3 and $s4 will be used.
    ############################################################################
    Function:

        addi    $sp, $sp, -12   #adjust stack pointer
        sw  $ra, 8($sp) #save return address    
        sw  $a0, 4($sp) #save n
        sw  $s0, 0($sp) #save immediate value (used for storing function(n-1))  


        li  $t2, 15

        slti    $t0, $a0, 6
        beq $t0, $zero, GreaterThanFive


    LessThanFive:
        add     $t1, $a0, $zero
        add $t1, $t1, $a0
        sub $t2, $t2, $t1
        move    $v0, $t2    
        j   Conclusion
    GreaterThanFive:

        addi    $a0, $a0, -1
        jal Function
        move    $s0, $v0

        lw  $a0, 4($sp)
        addi    $a0, $a0, -3
        jal Function


        lw  $a0, 4($sp)
        mul $t3, $a0, $s0
        sub $t4, $t3, $v0
        add $t5, $t4, $a0
        addi    $t6, $t5, -23

        move    $v0, $t6    

    Conclusion: 

        lw      $s1,0($sp)              # restore intermediate value
        lw  $a0,4($sp)
        lw  $ra,8($sp)

            addi    $sp,$sp,12              # restore stack

        jr  $ra             #return to caller```
````

Comment: Did you single-step through your function in the debugger to see what happens for that failing testcase?  This [mcve] isn't very minimal: debug on your own with the debugger until you get to a specific case (one small block) where something happens that you don't want and can't understand.

Comment: So when I go through single-step, it works perfectly fine until it exists the second recursion at `lw  $a0, 4($sp)
        mul $t3, $a0, $s0
        sub $t4, $t3, $v0
        add $t5, $t4, $a0
        addi    $t6, $t5, -23`
when a0, is 9. It multiplies a0 and s0, but gets 40 instead of the proper number that it should have of 180 (9*20) 9 from a0, and 20 from the results of f(n-1). I dont know why I get the wrong answer particularly because my s0 register might be saving the wrong answer but idk why it is saving the wrong answer.

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't loading the proper $s0, so i changed it to `lw $v0, 4($sp)` and further down i added `lw $s0, 4($sp)` which fixed the problem

Comment: Congrats on debugging it yourself.  Feel free to post the solution as an answer to your question, not just a comment.  (Although honestly the chance of anyone having exactly the same bug as you is very small so there's little future value in an answer explaining what your bug was.  And if they do have the same bug, hard to imagine search terms that would let them find this question.  Especially before they debug it enough to know exactly what their bug is...)